# How to throw an alert if any PID in linux goes above a certain limit?

Tags: linux, performance, process, monitor

I want to make a process monitor that runs in the background and does not take up a bunch of memory. I will be logging in to the remote computer via SSH and if at all possible would like to run the script on my local computer. I need it to throw an alert (audible?) when any running process goes above a predefined limit for CPU and MEM.

Is there any way to get values from 'top'? I have tried several 'ps' commands but not much luck..

Comment: what command or code did you try ? example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps` should give you cpu and memory usage of a pid.

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem
```

Results :

```
%CPU %MEM
12.9  0.9
```

Something to get you going. This script (`test.bash`) will throw a message if the CPU limit is above 50% and MEM limit is above 20%. It takes pid as an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

pid=$1
clim=50
mlim=20
ps -p $pid -o %cpu,%mem | grep "^[0-9].*" > /tmp/test.txt

while read cpu mem
do
    if [ $(bc <<< "$cpu > $clim") == 1 ]; then
        echo "CPU ($cpu) is above limit for PID:$pid"
    fi
    if [ $(bc <<< "$mem > $mlim") == 1 ]; then
        echo "MEM ($mem) is above limit for PID:$pid"
    fi
done < /tmp/test.txt
```

Run the script:

```
]$ ./test.bash 1918
CPU (50.2) is above limit for PID:1918
MEM (20.1) is above limit for PID:1918
```

Comment: Is there a way to loop through all pid's?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script I pieced together. Hope some one finds this useful. You can change the max_percent variable at the top to suit your needs. sleeper variable is the interval (in seconds) at which the loop executes.

```
#!/bin/bash
# alarm.sh
max_percent=94
sleeper=1
frequency=1000
duration=300

# To enable the script:
# chmod u+x alert.sh

# get the total available memory:
function total_memory {
    echo "Total memory available: "
    TOTAL_MEM=$(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}')
    #Another way of doing that:
    #total_mem=$(awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo)
    echo "---------- $TOTAL_MEM ---------------"
}


# alarm function params: frequency, duration
# Example:
# _alarm 400 200
_alarm() {
  ( \speaker-test --frequency $1 --test sine )&
  pid=$!
  \sleep 0.${2}s
  \kill -9 $pid
}

function total_available_memory {
    total_available_mem=$(</proc/meminfo grep MemTotal | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
    total_free_mem=$(</proc/meminfo grep MemFree | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
    total_used_mem=$((total_available_mem - total_free_mem))
    #percent_used=$((total_available_mem / total_free_mem))
    # print the free memory
    # customize the unit based on the format of your /proc/meminfo
    percent_used=$(printf '%i %i' $total_used_mem $total_available_mem | awk '{ pc=100*$1/$2; i=int(pc); print (pc-i<0.5)?i:i+1 }')

    if [ $percent_used -gt $max_percent ]; then
        echo "TOO MUCH MEMORY IS BEIGN USED!!!!!!!! KILL IT!"
        _alarm $frequency $duration
    fi

    echo "Available: $total_available_mem kb  -  Used: $total_used_mem kb  -  Free: $total_free_mem kb  -  Percent Used: $percent_used %"

}

# RUN THE FUNCTIONS IN AN INFINITE LOOP:
# total_memory

echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
while :
do
    total_available_memory
    sleep $sleeper
done
```